# Using rename_all to remove numbers from column names

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I am trying to remove the numbers from some column names that I have. I have tried the following without luck.

```
iris %>% 
  rename_all(.funs = list(gsub('[[:digit:]]+', "", names(.))))
```

How can I use `rename_all` to remove the numbers from the column names correctly?

Data:

```
data(iris)
numericNames <- paste(seq(1:5), colnames(iris), sep = "")
colnames(iris) <- numericNames
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the scoped variant `rename_all` has been superseded as of `dplyr` version 1.0.0, you should use `rename_with` like this:

```
iris %>% 
  rename_with(~gsub("\\d+", "", .))
```

or, using the regular expression you used

```
iris %>% 
  rename_with(~gsub('[[:digit:]]+', "", .))
```

The `.` refers to the name of the column, so you don't need to use `names(.)`

Output

```
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In `rename_all` column names are passed directly.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%  rename_all(~gsub('[[:digit:]]+', "", .)) %>% head

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```